# How to create histogram to visualize feature's value in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis-3

Is there any tool or plugin can create a plot like this (generated by Arcmap 10.7)? My QGIS software's version is 3.10.[image]  What I know is that the QGIS built-in tool, `basic statisc for field`, provides only some statistics, no plot available.

Comment: Have you had a look at the diagram-options in the labeling-toolbar?

Comment: @Erik Not yet. Since I have got used to ArcMap software, the shift from ArcMap to QGIS is a bit hard. I will have a close look at the label toolbar. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you open up your tool box (by hitting Ctrl + Alt + T) and navigate to Graphics you have a native tool named "Vector Layer histogram".

Here all you need to do is tell it what vector layer you want to analyse, choose the field you want to use and select the number of bins in the histogram. This uses the plotly library and you can export to plot.ly and change the design as you please.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone can't find Graphics in the toolbox, I'm using QGIS 3.16.7 and this grouping of tools is now called Plots instead of Graphics (definitely a better name).